# Export list of Dictionnary from python to excel

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

have a list called 'Aff' that consists of dictionaries. It looks like this:

```
Aff=[{('J', 0, 1): 36, ('J', 1, 1): 36, ('J', 2, 1): 42}, {('I', 0, 1): 36, ('I', 1, 1): 30}, {('H', 0, 1): 36, ('H', 1, 1): 36, ('H', 2, 1): 42}]
```

and i wanna get this structure on EXCEL :

```
-------Num------letter-----NV----Postion ---Q
        1         J         0       1       36
        1         J         1       1       36
        1         J         2       1       42
        2         I         0       1       36
        2         I         1       1       36 
...ect
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary keys consisting of tuple forces you to change the structure of your data. IIUC `Num` is the index (+1) of the dictionary in the list.

Once you flattened your data, you can use `pandas.to_excel()`:

```
import pandas as pd

Aff=[{('J', 0, 1): 36, ('J', 1, 1): 36, ('J', 2, 1): 42}, {('I', 0, 1): 36, ('I', 1, 1): 30}, {('H', 0, 1): 36, ('H', 1, 1): 36, ('H', 2, 1): 42}]

arr = []
for num, d in enumerate(Aff):
    for k,v in d.items():
        arr.append([num+1] + list(k) + [v])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['Num', 'letter', 'NV', 'Position', 'Q'])

df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

`print(df)` would output:

```
   Num letter  NV  Position   Q
0    1      J   0         1  36
1    1      J   1         1  36
2    1      J   2         1  42
3    2      I   0         1  36
4    2      I   1         1  30
5    3      H   0         1  36
6    3      H   1         1  36
7    3      H   2         1  42
```

Comment: There's no need to go through a dataframe here, you can just write the rows to openpyxl.

Comment: You're right! if no operation is needed on the df it'll be faster! pandas is just so convenient to manipulate tables ^^

Comment: Thank you can you explain this code to me

Comment: What do you want explanation for? Try printing some variables during execution (or even better: use a debugger) and reading the documentation of some of the methods: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate),  [items](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) or [ways to concatenate lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-concatenate-two-lists/)